# Upgrading to 16.04.3 LTS Caused Loss of Dual-Boot Ability

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Years ago, I partitioned my hard disk and installed Windows Vista at the beginning of the disk, and Ubuntu (maybe version 12 or so) behind it.  I was able to select which OS I wanted to use via the GRUB menu that appeared when booted.  A few months ago, I installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS over my old version and my problem is that I don't get the GRUB menu anymore - I am booted directly into Ubuntu.  when I run boot-repair, it tells me that the GRUB files need to be installed into a boot partition that is located in the first 1 GB of the drive.  So I wanted to create that partition as instructed with gParted on the LiveCD, but the instructions for that warn me about using gParted to resize the Windows partion - which is what i need to do because it's in the beginning of the disk.  It says I have to use Windows utilities to adjust my Windows OS partition.  But how can i do that if i can't boot into windows?  I'm stuck, and would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

you can try editing the `/etc/default/grub` file so it looks like this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="false"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="3"
```

Once set up like this you can save the file and run `sudo update-grub`
this should give you the menu at boot for 3 seconds .. you can change the timeout to your liking

Comment: Thank you for responding, @john-orion!  The only change I had to make to the `/etc/default/grub` was to change the `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` setting to `false`.  I didn't have to use quotes in my file... I don't know if that matters though.  I also tried changing the screen resolution setting from :

Comment: Sorry!  I just learned that `Enter` submits a comment.  To continue my previous comment:  I also tried changing the screen resolution setting from: `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` to `GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080` while I was in there.  Unfortunately that didn't help either.

Comment: yeah the screen resolution setting wont do anything ... Im not even sure it would accept that value mine is set to `GRUB_GFXMODE="1024x768x24"` maybe you can edit your questions and copy and paste in your grub file .... to make it look like I did .. you have to put 4 spaces before each line .. or if you cant get it .. someone will probably edit it for you :D